# Retina resolution splash screen image not showing for retina resolution

Tags: xcode, retina-display, splash-screen

I have set the retina resolution splash screen image in Launch Image in XCode 4.5.2 "Summary" tab... but for some reason the stretched non-retina resolution splash image still shows when I run my app...

How do you properly set the retina-resolution splash screen?

Comment: I assume you've named it correctly: Default@2x.png

Comment: Splash screens are not a standard component, so how is your splash screen displayed?

Comment: It looks like the project renamed it Default@2x and created a copy. The renamed version looks about right (isn't stretched)... Actual turns out to be stretched on device though. :(